# Why localStorage value is empty when page is refreshed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-context

I am using `Context API` to pass my Cart data to different pages, and trying to use `localStorage` to set and retrieve the Cart data while refreshing the page.

Setting the Cart data to `localStorage` after every change of the `state` is working fine, but the problem is that when the page is refreshed, the data of `localStorage` is gone and so the Cart data will be reset!

I don't understand where I'm doing something wrong and why `localStorage` data won't be set and used while page is refreshed. Can you please help me out with this? (For display purposes I'm just `log`ging the `localStorage` value for now.)

Here is my code:

```
function CartProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const [retrievedState, setRetrievedState] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart") || "") || initialState
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state));
    setRetrievedState(state);
  }, [state]);

  console.log(retrievedState);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: remember that localStorage is under the _user's_ control, not yours. If their browser is set to clear browsing data on exit: that data is gone. Don't use localStorage if you need to save session information, save it on the server side and load it in as part of a page request because you know which user is loading a page (either because of a login/cookie, but cookies _also_ get wiped if the user has the browser set to clear data, so there's that). Having said that, your useEffect is going to set "cart" to whatever `state` is, so: find out what you're actually saving to localStorage?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I know that. And my aim is to use `localStorage` features while the page is refreshed accidentally for convenience of the user, assuming that they have kept the default settings of their `localStorage` browser, and mine is not changed either.

Comment: Then you'll want to console log before that setItem call, to see what you're _really_ putting in there.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Just checked that. What I'm trying to set as `cart` in the `localStorage` is the right `cart` data the user is putting in. The `localStorage` value is set correctly while not having had refreshed the page, as it is wiped out while page is reloaded.

Comment: Then it's probably time to turn that into a [mcve] (and then hopefully you spot the problem while doing so, but if not, at least you'll have reproducible code to ask folks for help with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that the solution for this issue is that we retrieve the `state` from `localStorage` when the `component` `mount`s (won't be needing `retrievedState` and it's `setRetrievedState` anymore), and if a value is found, we `dispatch` an `action` to hydrate the `state` with this value, and we update `localStorage` whenever the `state` changes, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    if (storedState) {
      dispatch({ type: "HYDRATE_STATE", payload: JSON.parse(storedState) });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state]);
```

And of course we should add a `'HYDRATE_STATE'` `action` appropriately to set the `state` with the `payload`. Something like this:

```
case "HYDRATE_STATE":
      return action.payload;
```

Answer (score 0):

In context provider, when you refresh, all values are set to empty/ initial state.

In your code you are using useEffect, so on first render you are setting the localStorage to a value from state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state));
    setRetrievedState(state);
  }, [state]);
```

If state is not already defined, then its going to set localStorage to empty, and when you change the state, localStorage is set again.

You should be inspecting the `state` variable and make sure that it has some values when page refreshes. Other than that I don't see any flaws in the code.

Comment: You are right! When the page is refreshed, the `state` becomes empty and that empty value is set to `retrievedState`. Do you know how I can make `state` keep the `localStorage` value while the page is refreshed?

Comment: I guess you have solved it, would be awesome if you can accept the answer

Comment: I really want to thank you for helping me find the problem. But I guess I have to accept my own answer for this question as it also has a solution. But I really appreciate your help and answers.